# Почему блокируется доступ к родителю фрейма?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, iframe

Есть сайт: `mydomain.com`. На сайте есть фрейм, который подгружает информацию с `mydomain.com/folder/index.html`.

В этом фрейме идет обращение через JS к родителю фрейма, т.е. основной странице, все отлично работает, но вот после запуска этого скрипта:

https://github.com/DmitryKoterov/dklab_realplexor/blob/master/dklab_realplexor.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/dklab_realplexor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var realplexor = new Dklab_Realplexor('http://rpl.mydomain.com/', 'test_');
        realplexor.subscribe("Alpha", function(data) { alert("Alpha: " + data) });
        realplexor.execute();

    });
</script>
```

Который создает еще 1 фрейм, подгружая в него примерно такую информацию: https://github.com/DmitryKoterov/dklab_realplexor/blob/master/dklab_realplexor.html

При обращении с 1 фрейма к parent, например: `parent.myFunction();`, я получаю ошибку:

> Error: Permission denied to access property "myFunction"

Почему так? Как получить доступ к функции родительского элемента в таком случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В скрипте https://github.com/DmitryKoterov/dklab_realplexor/blob/master/dklab_realplexor.js#L49 в строке 49 написано:

```
document.domain = host; // в строе 9:  var host = document.location.host;
```

У всех страницах общающихся меж собой подобным образом должен быть установлен одинаковый `document.domain`

Comment: document.domain в 1 фрейме (с которого блокируется доступ к родителю) соответствует тому, который в document.domain = host;

Comment: @entermix, а вы прямо под дебагом проверьте на всякий случай

Comment: Вот так: 1. Родитель (mydomain.com): alert(document.domain);  // mydomain.com
2. 1 фрейм (mydomain.com/folder/index.html): alert(document.domain);  // mydomain.com

Перед это строчкой: document.domain = host;, тоже alert(document.domain);  // mydomain.com

Comment: 1 фрейм, открывается при помощи http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: да и вообще со всех фреймов на странице пропадает доступ к родителю после запуска Dklab_Realplexor

Comment: скиньте адрес вашей страницы

Comment: Написал Вам на почту, указанную на github